# Creating ::after pseudo element causing problems with backface-visibility

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a flip card that has a shadow that fades in and out as it flips. I've read that the most efficient way (in terms of rendering) to animate a shadow is to create an ::after pseudo element with opacity of 0 and fade the shadow in. I'm attaching two snippets, one without the shadows that works fine, and the second that has the shadows and has a weird effect. Essentially, when the pseudo elements are there, the backface-visiblity property seems to glitch (or I'm missing something) but basically the back of the card shows immediately before it's even flipped over. I've slowed down the animation and added a red shadow to the back of the card so that it's easy to see what all is happening.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.card {
  perspective: 50rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8); 
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;}
  .card--flip {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none; }
  .card__side {
  
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #777;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden; }
    .card__side--front::after {
      box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);    
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 3s ease; }
    .card__side--back {
      transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
      .card__side--back::after {
        box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 3s ease; }
  .card:hover .card__side--front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    .card:hover .card__side--front::after {
      opacity: 0; }
  .card:hover .card__side--back {
    transform: rotateY(0); }
    .card:hover .card__side--back::after {
      opacity: 1; }
  .card__header {
    padding: 2rem; }
  .card__main {
    padding: 2rem; }
```

```html
      WORKING
      <div class="card card--flip">
        <div class="card__side card__side--front">
          <div class="card__header">
            <h1>FRONT</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card__main">front</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card__side card__side--back">
          <div class="card__header">
            <h1>BACK</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card__main">back</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```css
.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  perspective: 50rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8); }
  .card--flip {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none; }
  .card__side {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #777;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden; }
    
 /* ADDED PSEUDO ELEMENT */
    .card__side::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -10;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; }
 
  
    .card__side--front::after {
      box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 3s ease; }
    .card__side--back {
      transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
      .card__side--back::after {
        box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 3s ease; }
  .card:hover .card__side--front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    .card:hover .card__side--front::after {
      opacity: 0; }
  .card:hover .card__side--back {
    transform: rotateY(0); }
    .card:hover .card__side--back::after {
      opacity: 1; }
  .card__header {
    padding: 2rem; }
  .card__main {
    padding: 2rem; }
```

```html
      NOT WORKING
      (added pseudo ::after class)
      <div class="card card--flip">
        <div class="card__side card__side--front">
          <div class="card__header">
            <h1>FRONT</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card__main">front</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card__side card__side--back">
          <div class="card__header">
            <h1>BACK</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card__main">back</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your class:

```
  .card {
  ...
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
```